# How to remove post name from WP_Query url when used in pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Is this possible?

I am trying to get pagination working on my pages and single pages. It seems like it's working, as it recognizes how many pages there are and shows the URL. The problem: the URL is wrong!

**Functions.php:**

```
function pagination_bar( $query_wp ) 
{
    $pages = $query_wp->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if ($pages > 1)
    {
        $page_current = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $page_current,
            'total' => $pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

The query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(  array( 'posts_per_page' => 25,
                                           'paged' => $paged
                                            ) ); 
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

The HTML:

```
    <nav class="pagination">
<?php pagination_bar( $the_query ); ?>
```

What URL I am getting when pagination is activated and clicked upon the next page:

> https://example.com/my_postorpagename/page/3/

What I want to get:

> https://example.com/page/3/

Question: (how) can I do this?

**Edit:**
I also tried to edit it like

```
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( "https://mywebsitename.com%_%" ) ) ),
```

But then it gives me only my `URL`, without the `/page/x`...

Comment: will it even work without pointing to the article? anyway... you need to modify `get_pagenum_link()` in `wp-includes/link-template.php`

Comment: Is there no other way? I mean, I don't want to touch the core...

Comment: you can try to replace `get_pagenum_link( $big )` with fixed url, sorry don't have WP anywhere installed, to check that out, function itself doesn't allow you to change it by additional parameter

Comment: try to replace it with `https://mywebsitename.com%_%` and set format to `/page/%#%`

Comment: Tried it, but then it just removes the /page/x and shows me just the URL. So seems like it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I got it to work by changing the base like this:

From:

```
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
```

To:

```
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', "http://example.com/page/$big" ),
```